# What is the proper Huawei AT-command for STK to enter data

Tags: at-command, modem, sim-toolkit, huawei-mobile-services

This is what I get when I run AT^STGI command:

```
AT^STGI=3,1    
^STGI:"456E74657220796F75722050494E",4,2,0,0,4,6,0
```

The text says "Enter your PIN:"

From Huawei Manual (HUAWEI MG323 Series Wireless Module AT Command Interface Specification.PDF) - page 260

```
4 = (text code) 8-bit coding    
2 = (rspFormat) Digits (0-9, *, #, +)    
0 = (PackMode) Uncompressed mode    
0 = (EchoMode) disable    
4 = (size min)    
6 = (size max)    
0 = (help info)
```

I tried both these lines below but NO luck so far. PIN is 1234, the first line is 1234 in ASCI, second line is hex.

```
AT^STGR=3,1,4,1234
AT^STGR=3,1,4,31323334
```

STGR syntax from page 266 says

```
4 = "Get Input" reported by SIM card is supported by MT.
<Data>: indicates that includes the characters input by user.
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW the system accepts the command, I see 'OK' but nothing happens. It is suppose to receive a SMS from telco.

Comment: I am quite sure the pin code is supposed to be given as a string and not as a number, e.g. `AT^STGR=3,1,4,"1234"`.

Comment: I tried that but no luck

Comment: I wonder whether 4 is the right one to use, this is from the manual:

`Parameter Values in the Response When CmdType=3 (Get Input)
<CmdIndex>: it is consistent with <CmdIndex> reported by the ^STIN command.
<Result>:
0: The user terminated the session.
1: The command is executed successfully.
2: The help information required by the user.
4: "Get Input" reported by SIM card is supported by MT.
<Data>: indicates that includes the characters input by user.
`

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: you need to press CTRL+Z at the end.